# Should zabbix server be online all the time

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am new to server management and unix. I want a monitoring solution for my personal web server. I want to try zabbix but I want to ask; does zabbix server have to be online always? or can I install it on my personal computer and use it like "hey whatsup there on my server?".

I don't know if the server collects data and logs it itself continuously or use logs stored on remote zabbix clients.

Answer (score 2):

The server must be running continuously in order to collect data from the machines to be monitored.

Answer (score 0):

The zabbix server has to run all the time.
You may be better with a third party solution if you don't want to run it 24x7.
Look at http://www.uptimerobot.com/